# React + Flux data errors produce snackbar notification?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439908/dispatch-a-redux-action-with-the-subsequent-action-as-payload-to-show-a-snackbar%20*this%20question*), I'm using material UI and React, and I want to display a Snackbar notification on data error.

*The notable difference is I'm doing this in a fairly stock Flux way, not Redux.*

Specifically, if a `fetch` operation can't connect to the backend servers, I want to display a snackbar notification informing the user.

In my understanding of Flux, the UI emits actions which affect stores, in a one-way fashion.  Since the error is happening in the data store asyncronously, how do I bubble the error up to the snackbar?

**action**

```
export default {
  loginUser: () => {
    AppDispatcher.dispatch({ actionType: LOGIN });
  }
}
```

**store**

```
class LoginStore extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.snackbarError = undefined
  }
  _registerToActions(action) {
    switch(action.actionType) {
      case LOGIN:
        fetch('/auth').catch((error) => {
          this.snackbarError = 'Auth failed!'
        })
        this.emitChange();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**component**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  // how do I trigger snackbar.show() when LoginStore.snackbarError set?

  render (
    <h3>My Component</h3>
    <button onClick={LoginAction.loginUser}>Login</button>
    <Snackbar message={LoginStore.snackbarError} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
class LoginStore extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.snackbarError = undefined
  }
  _registerToActions(action) {
    switch(action.actionType) {
      case LOGIN:
        fetch('/auth').catch((error) => {
          this.snackbarError = 'Auth failed!'
          this.emitSomeWhoCallMyComponent();
        })

        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  // how do I trigger snackbar.show() when LoginStore.snackbarError set?
  componentDidMount()
  {
    this._doSomething = () => doSomething();
    LoginStore.addSomeWhoCallMyComponentListener(this._doSomething);
  }

  doSomething()
  {
    snackbar.show();
  }
  render (
    <h3>My Component</h3>
    <button onClick={LoginAction.loginUser}>Login</button>
    <Snackbar message={LoginStore.snackbarError}  />
  )
}
```